# Weird error message on Codepen

Tags: css, sass, codepen

i have this code on Codepen:

```
body {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black), 
  linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-position:0 0, 30px 30px;
}
```

for some reason I get this message:

> Invalid CSS after "100px": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was
>   ";"

Any idea what's going on?

[see it on Codepen](http://codepen.io/isaacalves/pen/OWoQGP)

Comment: You have set the CSS panel to use SASS as CSS precompiler. I'm not familiar with the SASS syntax, so I can't say why that's causing an error - just want to make sure you are aware of that, because when I disable SASS so pure CSS is used, it works.

Comment: That's right, it works with CSS but as far as I know Sass should interpret CSS. And if I convert it back to Sass after converting to CSS, it also works.

Answer (score 4):

When using SASS, you don't need any curly brackets or semicolons. You also have to get rid of any line breaks in comma separated values.

I don't know about the backwards-capability of SASS to CSS, but see the Codepen working with SASS enabled:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygxKvK

```
body
  width: 100px
  height: 100px
  background-color: #eee
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black),  linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black)
  background-size: 60px 60px
  background-position: 0 0, 30px 30px
```

Comment: The `scss` syntax is always more preferable than `sass`. Check http://thesassway.com/editorial/sass-vs-scss-which-syntax-is-better

Comment: @nashcheez the OP didn't ask which is better, the question was why do they have the error. This question states the error (using curly braces when you shouldn't) so thereby is the correct answer

Comment: @CalvT And as the OP himself answered below that he was confusing `scss` with `sass` and was in fact writing `scss` code, suggesting an answer with `sass` code should not be a general solution imo.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/isaacalves/pen/OWoQGP - This works now.

Just set the CSS pre-processor settings as `SCSS`

Answer (score 0):

I was just confusing Sass with Scss.

http://thesassway.com/editorial/sass-vs-scss-which-syntax-is-better